# jquery - Remove html if width is less than 767px

Tags: jquery, width, detect

Currently, I have a modal pop-up (Shadowbox) for a "feedback" form to our site. I am fine with the modal on desktop browsers, but I want to open a new "page" on a mobile browser (less than 767px) and do away with modal complications on mobile devices.

Is there a jquery solution to remove the 'rel="shadowbox"' element from the link code so that it just opens a new browser window?

Example:

Desktop Version

```
<a href="site.com" target="_blank" rel="shadowbox">Link</a>
```

767px or less Version

```
<a href="site.com" target="_blank">Link</a>
```

So far I have this script:

```
<script>
$( "a" )
  .contents()
  .filter(function(){
    return this.nodeType !== 1;
  })
  .remove( "rel="shadowbox"" );
</script>
```

I cannot figure out how to first detect width to apply the "if, then".

Help is much appreciated! I, admittedly, do not work with JS as much as I need to.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/HcxwE/

```
if($(window).width() < 768){
    console.log('kill shadowbox');
    $("a[rel='shadowbox']" ).removeAttr('rel');
}
```

You may encounter issues with the listeners are attached to the elements prior to the shadowbox rel being removed.

See this fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/qV882/

Answer (score 0):

You can get any css property using jquery's .css() function

```
if ( $(this).css('width') <= '767' ){

    // Do things here
}
```

Then you can give an id to your link and use .removeAttr()

```
// Do things here
$('#my_a').removeAttr('rel');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (document.width < 767) {
   $.remove( "rel="shadowbox" );
}
```